# OnClick automático na função

Tags: javascript

Pessoal explicando um pouco como funciona o sistema.

Quando o usuário inserir um valor abaixo da meta estabelecida, automaticamente abre um modal para preencher um "plano de ação".

Ao preencher o plano, ele pode criar outras ações ou concluir, mas se ele deixar em aberto, toda vez ao entrar nesse local,  irá aparecer outro modal informando que existe um plano em aberto.

Se o usuário fechar o sistema e voltar para analisar esse plano, o certo séria: Aparece esse "Modal Info" ele clicar no botão e o levaria para a pagina do plano.

Err: Ao voltar eu não sei o que raios fiz, o OnClick ficou automático. Assim que entra na área, os sistema detecta que tem um plano aberto, e já abre a pagina do mesmo. Segue o código da função abaixo.

```js
function showModals(indicadorID, name, city, month, year, role){
    checkPlan(name, city, year, function (result) {
        //Exemplo de operacao
        //mes a definir em indicadorForaDaMeta
        checkIndicadorMeta(name, city, month, year, role, function (indicadorForaDaMeta) {
            var mesAtual = new Date().getMonth();
            if (result.length == 0) {
                var mesDoUltimoPlano = mesAtual - 1;
            } else {
                var mesDoUltimoPlano = new Date(result[result.length - 1].pla_data).getMonth();
            }
            console.log(result);
            if (indicadorForaDaMeta && !(mesAtual == mesDoUltimoPlano)) {
                $('#add-modal-plano-de-acao-form').find('[name="id"]').val(indicadorID);
                $('#add-modal-plano-de-acao').modal('show');
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if (result[i].pla_status) {
                        var month = new Date(result[i].pla_data).getMonth() + 1;
                        var year = new Date(result[i].pla_data).getFullYear();
                        $('#info-modal-plano-de-acao-form').find('[name="id"]').val(result[i].pla_id);
                        $('#info-modal-plano-de-acao-form').find('[name="month"]').val(month);
                        $('#info-modal-plano-de-acao-form').find('[name="year"]').val(year);
                        $('#info-modal-plano-de-acao').modal('show');
                        console.log("#" + convertNameToId(name) + "-botao-plano");
                        $('#' + convertNameToId(name) + '-botao-plano').removeAttr('onClick');
                        $('#' + convertNameToId(name) + '-botao-plano').attr('onClick', abrirPlano(result[i].pla_id, month, year));
                       
                        i = result.length; 
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: `.attr('onClick'` não é a forma correta de atribuir código ao evento de click. Em jquery, que parece ser o que está a usar, deve fazer `.on('click', function() {....}`, ou na versão antiga `.click(function(){ ... }`. Na sequencia disto o `.removeAttr('onClick')` seria `.unbind('click')`

Comment: @Isac obrigado. Fiz as alterações que você sugeriu e deu certo, não está mais automático, mas... O botão do madal está a funcionar, mas ou outro botão não está. Segue o código.

//código
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="exemplo-botao-plano">Plano de Ação</button>

Answer (score 0):

Isto acontece porque nesta linha:

```
$('#' + convertNameToId(name) + '-botao-plano').attr('onClick', abrirPlano(result[i].pla_id, month, year));
```

estás expressamente a dizer que o atributo "onclick" tem o valor do resultado da função.

experimenta trocar para usar um [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Glossary/Callback_function):

```
$('#' + convertNameToId(name) + '-botao-plano').attr('onClick', function() { abrirPlano(result[i].pla_id, month, year) });
```

assim, o atributo do "onclick" ganha o valor da função anonima que quando é chamada vai chamar a função `abrirPlano(....)`

Comment: MoshMage, Obrigado!
Fiz as alterações que você sugeriu, mas ainda continua automático.

Comment: @Letimberg estranho. Não devia. Esse é o unico codigo que mete o valor do atributo onclick a esse elemento ? não há mais nenhum codigo que faça isso?!

Comment: sim. A solução que o amigo Isac mencionou, funcionou parcialmente.